# How can I get awk input from a file and add my own text to the data?

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

Assume that I have a text file separated by colons. I understand how to display the entire text file or any specific column using `awk`. However, what I want to do is to get the `awk` output and then display it by adding my own text using a shell script? For example, assume that my text file is:

```
England:London:GMT
USA:Washington:EST
France:Paris:GMT
```

What I want to do is to display this input into the below format:

```
COUNTRY: England
CAPITOL: London
TIMEZONE: GMT

COUNTRY: USA
CAPITOL: Washington
TIMEZONE: EST

COUNTRY: France
CAPITOL: Paris
TIMEZONE: GMT
```

Comment: Please note that the file sample and output sample are not displaying the way I intended it to be. England:London:GMT should be one line and similarly USA and France should have info in 2nd and 3rd lines. For the output, COUNTRY: England should be one line and followed by CAPITOL:London and so on

Comment: I'm not sure the French will look kindly on being assigned to GMT time zone; they run an hour ahead of the UK.

Comment: @xs2dhillon: you just posted a query about XML and XPath, but deleted it. I tend to suggest (especially to new users) that this is poor practice, since someone may have been in the middle of answering it. If you need(ed) an answer to it, it is much better to improve it in line with the advice you were receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F: '{printf "COUNTRY: %s\nCAPITOL: %s\nTIMEZONE: %s\n\n",$1,$2,$3}'
```

as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'England:London:GMT
...> USA:Washington:EST
...> France:Paris:GMT' |awk -F: '
...>     {printf "COUNTRY: %s\nCAPITOL: %s\nTIMEZONE: %s\n\n",$1,$2,$3}'
COUNTRY: England
CAPITOL: London
TIMEZONE: GMT

COUNTRY: USA
CAPITOL: Washington
TIMEZONE: EST

COUNTRY: France
CAPITOL: Paris
TIMEZONE: GMT
```

Comment: Thank you much for the quick responses. I have implemented the first suggestion given by Jonathan and it did work.

Comment: @xs2dhillon, then you should accept the answer that best answered your question (prob. Jonathan's) and upvote all those that you consider useful, hopefully including mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply print the extra data:

```
awk -F: '{ print "COUNTRY: " $1;
           print "CAPITOL: " $2;
           print "TIMEZONE: " $3;
           print "";
         }' text_file
```

The plain `print` adds a newline to what it prints.  In `awk`, string concatenation is done by placing the strings (or variables) adjacent to each other — no commas or other operators needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without awk:

```
<FILE  tr : '\n' | 
    xargs printf "COUNTRY: %s\nCAPITOL: %s\nTIMEZONE: %s\n\n"
```

where FILE is your data file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^/COUNTRY: /;s/:/\nCAPITOL: /2;s/:/\nTIMEZONE: /3;$!s/$/\n/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk in shell while block code:

```
  cat text | while read line 
  do
      echo $line | awk -F: '{print "COUNTRY: ", $1, "\nCAPITOL: ", $2, "\nTIMEZONE: ", $3, "\n"}'
  done
```

Comment: awk will do that loop for you automatically. There's no need to invoke  awk for each line individually. What you show is very inefficient.

Comment: yeah,you are right. "awk -F: '{print "COUNTRY: ",$1,"\nCAPITOL: ",$2,"\nTIMEZONE: ",$3,"\n"}' text " . this is enough . Thanks!